# How to dynamically construct a function's arguments without eval?

Tags: javascript

Given this code:

```
var arr = ['one', 'two'];
var obj = {
  func: function(a, b) {
    console.log(a, b);
  }
};
```

Is there a way to dynamically construct the function call passing the items in the array as arguments without using `eval()`? Basically, the equivalent of this:

`eval('obj.func(' + arr.join(',') + ')');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the array into the argument list:

```js
var arr = ['one', 'two'];
var obj = {
  func: function(a, b) {
    console.log(a, b);
  }
};
obj.func(...arr);
```

Or, if the environment doesn't support spread, you can use `apply`, which allows you to call a function with the supplied array converted to parameters:

```js
var arr = ['one', 'two'];
var obj = {
  func: function(a, b) {
    console.log(a, b);
  }
};
obj.func.apply(undefined, arr);
```

Comment: Spread is just what I was looking for. Learned something new today -- thanks!

Comment: To add on that, for browsers without ES6 (`*cough*`IE`*cough*), you can use the `arguments` variable, present in every single function. Also, instead of `obj.func.apply(undefined, arr);`, use `obj.func.apply(this, arr);` (or `window`, instead of `this`, but both will result in the same).

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Unless the function is *expecting* some particular `this` value, isn't it better to set the this to `undefined` (rather than to `window` which subsequently goes unused)?

Comment: Well, if you don't define a `this` to a function, the `this` will be `window`. Setting to `undefined` breaks that expectation. Just run `(_=>this)()` in F12, and you will see what I mean.